# Establishing a connection between data given using istringstream and struct/vector

Tags: c++

I have the following data in a file, let the columns be [A    B    C    D    E]:

a1 b1 c1 d1 e1

a2 b2 c2 d2 e2

a3 b3 c3 d3 e3

.....

All are integers. A is just the serial number. let B be a node having only max of 4 terminals. C represents which terminal of B is taken. Similarly, D is a node having max of 4 terminals and E represents the terminal of D choosen. example: c1 of b1 is connected to e2 of d2.

I have successfully read the data from the files line by line using istringstream and getline as below:

```
 while (getline(infile, line))
{
    int i=0;
    istringstream iss(line); // string stream
    while(getline(iss, temp[i]))
    {

        cout<< temp[i] << endl;
        ++i;
    };
}
```

I am not able to conclude on how to save the connections mentions above line to line. I am new to c++ and would appreciate any ideas and implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can just declare a `vector<vector<int>> nameVector`,(give it a size) and inside of while you put the data. Or be more specific on what you want.